# Postgresql: Select 6M rows - takes 5min?

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing

When I select from the table below (containing 6 milion rows) it takes 5 minutes to complete the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM public.matchmsg order by tradeid desc
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Table definition**

```
CREATE TABLE public.matchmsg
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('matchmsg_id_seq'::regclass),
  tradeid bigint NOT NULL,
  matchdate timestamp with time zone,
  price double precision NOT NULL,
  size double precision NOT NULL,
  issell boolean NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT matchmsg_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE,
  autovacuum_enabled=true
);
ALTER TABLE public.matchmsg
  OWNER TO mb;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tradeid_idx
  ON public.matchmsg
  USING btree
  (tradeid);
```

UPDATE 1:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT * FROM public.matchmsg;

"Seq Scan on matchmsg  (cost=0.00..117720.03 rows=6000103 width=41) (actual time=0.041..837.495 rows=6000102 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 1.769 ms"
"Execution time: 914.932 ms"
```

Is the query supposed to execute in 117 sec?

UPDATE 2:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT * FROM public.matchmsg order by tradeid

"Index Scan using tradeid_idx on matchmsg  (cost=0.43..278622.57 rows=6177667 width=41) (actual time=0.172..1465.935 rows=6177670 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 0.246 ms"
"Execution time: 1553.377 ms"
```

UPDATE 3:

To get the right and proper answer you also have to ask the right question...and  may be i didnt... i realized that just selecting 6M rows does not make much sense...But thus the fact i did - and i didnt understand why my pc was so slow to give me a proper response (and i still dont - no matter of DB, UI or what ever - i think 5 min is way too slow - Im using Postgres own native tools: PG Enterprise M. or the PG pgAdminIII - they are like identical). What tools is faster/better, what do you guys use with Postgresql?

I do now also realize that an index doesnt help any thing - when i select all rows and all columns.

I tried to run the CLUSTER statement - but it didnt change anything - as far as i could tell...?

What im going to do with the 6M rows? Well - im going to do a lot of different analysis with algorithm/patterns over time... so depending on the math/expressions i will need and how difficult/tough it will be to calculate ect... i think i have 2 options from here:

either to do all the needed math via SQL in the DB or load like 1000 rows(only certain column/s) into my nodejs code, do the math on the given loaded data...loop through the entire DB...

To your info the follow statements perform like this:

```
select SUM(price) from matchmsg --> about 1 sec!

SELECT tradeid FROM matchmsg order by tradeid asc limit 1000 offset 5000000 --> about 1 sec!
```

I also tried to execute the

```
"SELECT * FROM matchmsg"
```

inside nodeJS - but after 30 sec or so it crash - with the error desc:

```
"FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory".
```

But what is far more interesting is the fact that:

```
"SELECT tradeid FROM matchmsg" --> 7 sec!
```

And i could even pick out like resultset[5000000] and get the tradeid at that  position within the 7 sec inside my nodeJS app...

All these fact will make it all up in the end of the day - i just have to get down to the real math to understand which way to go...

Comment: It takes some time to retrieve 6M rows from the disk and to transfer it to the client.

Comment: Its on my local laptop (DELL XPS I7, 8GB, SSD) and i do the select statement wth "Postgres Enterprise Manager"

When i make a

EXPLAIN SELECT * matchmsg

It returns (cost=0.00..117720.3...)

So why does it take 5 times as long time?

Comment: Provide the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. "5 times as long time" --- 5 times as long compared to *what*? Cost is not in milliseconds

Comment: So the query has completed in `914.932` milliseconds. And it took 5 more minutes to send data to the client

Comment: "Is the query supposed to execute in 117 sec?" --- where do you see 117 seconds?

Comment: and by "to the client" you mean: To get the data from disk and show it in the manager window?

Comment: No, a network/socket transfer between a database server listener and your client.

Comment: But every thing is running on my localhost / laptop... both database and of course the Progresql Enterprise Manager software...? How can it be so slow? Sorry, but I still dont get it...

Comment: It is a lot of rows/data to be transferred. "Progresql Enterprise Manager software" --- being "enterprise" does not mean it will be instant. "How can it be so slow?" --- it's not obvious what you want to hear here: the query is performed quickly, everything else is consumed by data transfer/your client rendering. If you think it is slower than it should be - please provide some *technical arguments* for that. Just because it's local and "enterprise" does not guarantee it will work fast.

Comment: Well... i will give it a try... 6M row at 41 bytes each = 246.000.000 bytes / 246MB

How can it take 5min to transfer 246MB - inside the same laptop? Its equal to 0.82MB/sec?

Comment: 1. Take performance analysis tools and see what exactly is being slow http://techblog.netflix.com/2015/11/linux-performance-analysis-in-60s.html 2. My best guess is that the slowest here is a GUI application that renders all the 6M rows long grid at once. Try the same query in CLI, but forward output to the `/dev/null` - I'm sure it will be much faster.

Comment: Can you post the values of shared_buffers, work_mem and random_page_cost? Databases that grow will eventually hit some limits if these settings aren't modified. Especially the first value is important in such cases and may be enough to raise.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The EXPLAIN ANALYZE in the post misses the ORDER BY clause so is basically useless.

Comment: @Patrick: ah! I didn't see that - although even then it shouldn't take 5 minutes: http://explain.depesz.com/s/4h5C

Comment: FWITW: with my SQL client this takes about 40 seconds to retrieve and display the data including the `order by` (provided I give it enough memory). So I would very much assume it's a problem with that "enterprise manager" application. Is that a web application? Or a native client? But the **real** question is: what are you doing with 6 million rows once they are displayed?

Comment: Pablo, your query execution along with its planning takes less than 3 seconds. As a result, the issue has nothing to do with your database. The issue is that you transfer the data to the client-side (~250 megabytes) and when it's done, all your 6 million records are rendered graphically, which takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior. In such cases the main problem is usually the fact that the user has to wait a lot. You might consider the repeated sending of chunks of your data, to show a part of your data, while the whole data is being loaded. Also, you might consider using a paging, which is more-or-less a standard, but the waiting time for such a task is pretty normal.

Comment: 6M rows in 5 minutes is **not** normal behaviour. Otherwise your "answer" provides nothing but generic statements that do not help the OP in any way.

Comment: @Patrick it is a normal behaviour when a client renders those in a grid at once. It's a GUI, not postgresql problem.

Comment: @Patrick, try to generate a table with 6 million rows, use the same GUI to load, load the whole 6 million rows for the table (linear complexity), order them descendingly on an indexed column (nlogn), send it to the client-side (which is the very same computer in this case) and render them graphically. Then you will see that this is a time-consuming operation. So, the answer is that this is normal. I have described in general how can one improve the situation. I do not really understand your reason for being rude, I thought we are having friendly debates here.

Answer (score 0):

You should show us an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for the `SELECT` with the `ORDER BY` clause. What you will likely see is that the index is not being used. Since most time in ordered result set queries is taken up by the sorting, the unsorted `SELECT` provides no information whatsoever to resolve your issue. (With regards to 117 seconds of execute time: I presume you are referring to `cost=0.00..117720.03`, which is a relative measure of cost in arbitrary units, depending on the settings in `postgresql.conf`; it has nothing to do with time or any other physical property.)

By default the index is in `ASC`ending order and your query wants rows in `DESC`ending order. So either change your index to use descending order or create an additional index for this specific query:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tradeid_idx_desc
  ON public.matchmsg
  USING btree
  (tradeid DESC);
```

But even then the time will not be reduced because you are asking for all rows in the table so the index will not be used, but see below.

An alternative is to [`CLUSTER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-cluster.html) the table using the index above. This will result in a one-time physical sort of the table. If the rows are not often updated, then this will dramatically increase the speed of the query you are interested in. After a certain number of inserts of new rows the sorting speed will decrease because the clustering is not maintained by PG so you should periodically `CLUSTER` the table to maintain performance.

### Profiling

Seeing the discussion among the different posters and in the absence of the OP, I have recreated the OP table and run the various queries of interest.

The table is exactly the same. The `INSERT`statement:

```
INSERT INTO matchmsg (tradeid, matchdate, price, size, issell)
  SELECT (random() * 4100000000000000000)::bigint, now(), 3.23, 12.2, true
  FROM generate_series(1, 6000103);
```

The indexes, both `ASC` and `DESC` are not `UNIQUE` because of the random value assignment to `tradeid`.

```
patrick@puny:~$ psql -d test
psql (9.5.0, server 9.4.5)
Type "help" for help.

test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM matchmsg;
                                                      QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on matchmsg  (cost=0.00..116076.90 rows=6000090 width=37) (actual time=0.017..637.483 rows=6000103 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.601 ms
 Execution time: 854.207 ms
(3 rows)

test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM matchmsg ORDER BY tradeid DESC;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using tradeid_idx_desc on matchmsg  (cost=0.43..380121.64 rows=6000090 width=37) (actual time=0.056..15836.728 rows=6000103 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.234 ms
 Execution time: 16160.661 ms
(3 rows)

test=# CLUSTER matchmsg USING tradeid_idx_desc;
CLUSTER
test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM matchmsg ORDER BY tradeid DESC;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using tradeid_idx_desc on matchmsg  (cost=0.43..380121.84 rows=6000103 width=37) (actual time=0.029..1158.271 rows=6000103 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.289 ms
 Execution time: 1377.929 ms
(3 rows)
```

The simple `SELECT *` gives virtually the same performance metrics as the OP (this is a simple network, PG running on a separate machine). The `ORDER BY` query **does use** the `DESC` index but takes 16 seconds, due to the sorting. After `CLUSTER` on the descending index the query time goes down by a factor of 12 (give or take).

Comment: For a single column sorting there is no difference between index order - postgresql has no problems reading the index other way around to fulfill the order (in case if it really uses it, which is doubtful for this query anyway). "or create an additional index for this specific query" --- this advice is harmful.

Comment: "But even then the time will not be reduced dramatically" --- this is incorrect: for a 6M rows result set using index for ordering will be more expensive.

Comment: Now after you "fixed" the problem with the "But even then the time will not be reduced dramatically" --- the whole advice to change the index order makes no sense.

Comment: @zerkms The index is needed for the CLUSTER command and the whole discussion of indexes before was leading up to that. But yes, given that all rows and all columns are requested, an index will otherwise not be much use.